# Differentiability at $x=0$ for the following function

Tags: derivatives

Let $f:R\to R$ be a function such that $|f(x)|\le x^2$. What can we say about differentiability at $x=0?$

What I did is as follows:
$$-x^2\le f(x) \le x^2$$
$$\implies f(0) = 0,  Lim_{h\to0}f(h)=0$$.
Now, consider the left derivative,
$$LHD = Lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0)-f(-h)}{0-(-h)}=Lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-f(-h)}{h}$$ 
Similarly, the right derivative is,
$$RHD = Lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=Lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$$

Now as $h\to 0$, $f(h)$ as well as $f(-h)$ approach $0$. So we have $LHD=-RHD$, unless the derivative becomes $0$ at $f(0),$ in which case $LHD=RHD$.

So, what can I say about the differentiabilty? Intution says that it will be differentiable.

Comment: $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|=\left|\frac{f(x)}x\right|\leqslant|x|\to0\implies\lim_{x\to0}\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|=\ldots$$

Comment: Except in the first line, you never used the "bounded by $x^2$" assumption. Trying applying that to the last two limits you got.

Comment: Thank you everybody. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.

Note that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\frac{f(h)}h\right|\le\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^2}h$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it now :)